# Magento backend error: Edit user

Tags: magento, permissions, backend

I get an error in Magento 1.6.1.0 backend:
System -> Permissions -> Users -> Edit user

When I try to access this page nothing gets loaded into content area. Page layout and menus are displayed but the form for user editing is not.

In Firbug it throws the following error:

```
$("user_user_roles") is null
```

This line comes from

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/permissions/user_roles_grid_js.phtml
```

which has not been touched.

I did an update from 1.6.0.0 to 1.6.1.0 ... could create and edit users in the old version but I am not able to do it now. Could not find anything on the web for this error.

Please let me know if there is a fix to this.

Comment: What user name and what browser do you use? I tried to create new user with name 'user' in my CE 1.6.1.0 and all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. Here is what I did to fix. 
Open file Roles.php in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/User/Edit/Tab/Roles.php and add getRowUrl() function:

```
public function getRowUrl($row) {
  return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit');
}
```

Hope this helps,
Neo.